# Kubernetes MySql image persistent volume is non empty during init

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working through the persistent disks tutorial found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk) while also creating it as a StatefulSet instead of a deployment.

When I run the yaml file into GKE the database fails to start, looking at the logs it has the following error.

> [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.

Is it possible to inspect the volume created to see what is in the directory? Otherwise, what am I doing wrong that is causing the disk to be non empty?

Thanks

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datalayer-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: datalayer-svc
  labels:
    app: myapplication
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: dbadmin
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: database
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: datalayer
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapplication
  serviceName: "datalayer-svc"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapplication
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: database
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        env:
        - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-root-password
              key: password
        - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
          value: "appdatabase"
        - name: "MYSQL_USER"
          value: "app_user"
        - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
          value: "app_password"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datalayer-pv
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: datalayer-pv
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: datalayer-pvc
```

Comment: This is not google-kubernetes-engine specific, had the same problem in azure kubernetes service.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This issue could be caused by the `lost+found` directory on the filesystem of the PersistentVolume.

I was able to verify this by adding a `k8s.gcr.io/busybox` container (in PVC set `accessModes: [ReadWriteMany]`, OR comment out the `database` container):

```
- name: init
  image: "k8s.gcr.io/busybox"
  command: ["/bin/sh","-c","ls -l /var/lib/mysql"]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: database
    mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
```

There are a few potential workarounds...

Most preferable is to use a [`subPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) on the `volumeMounts` object. This uses a subdirectory of the PersistentVolume, which should be empty at creation time, instead of the volume root:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: database
  mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
  subPath: mysql
```

Less preferable workarounds include:

- Use a one-time container to `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/lost+found` (not a great solution, because the directory is managed by the filesystem and is likely to re-appear)
- Use `mysql:5` image, and add `args: ["--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"]` to the container (this option was removed in mysql 8)
- Use `mariadb` image instead of `mysql`

More details might be available at docker-library/mysql issues: [#69](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69) and [#186](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186)

Comment: Thank you for the subPath solution.... wasted a good 2 hours on this irritation.   Using mySql 8.0.13 which got rid of the ignore-db-dir option... so that didn't work for me... and removing the lost+found is def not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You would usually see if your volumes were mounted with:

```
kubectl get pods # gets you all the pods on the default namespace
# and
kubectl describe pod <pod-created-by-your-statefulset>
```

Then you can these commands to check on your PVs and PVCs

```
kubectl get pv  # gets all the PVs on the default namespace
kubectl get pvc # same for PVCs
kubectl describe pv <pv-name>
kubectl describe pvc <pvc-name>
```

Then you can to the GCP console on disks and see if your disks got created:

[image: GCP]

Comment: The disks are there, it it possible to see the contents of the disk? I would really like to get to the bottom of why the mysql docker image doesnt start

Comment: Yes, you can add it to a VM in stopped state, then start it and mount it on its local filesystem.

Comment: thanks Rico. I have connected to the VM and the mount points for the drives is all the same.{ /home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs/var/lib/} so I am a little lost as to how this works. Are you able to run my yaml script and see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the ignore dir lost+found

```
containers:
  - image: mysql:5.7
    name: mysql
    args:
    - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a init container to remove that file (I'm using postgres in my case):

```
      initContainers:
        - name: busybox
          image: busybox:latest
          args: ["rm", "-rf", "/var/lib/postgresql/data/lost+found"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfsv-db
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
```